# Nuxt 3 custom layout shows Invalid layout selected

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am trying to add a custom layout in a Nuxt 3 project, but that layout doesn't work, and the console shows this message:

> Invalid layout test_layout selected

There is no other error.

This the code I have tried:

```
-| layouts/
 ---| test_layout.vue
-| pages/
 ---| blog/index.vue
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    My Test Layout Header
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "test_layout"
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>My Blog Title</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout:"test_layout",
  name: "blog",
}
</script>
```

I have tried `<Nuxt/>` instead of `<slot />`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nuxt 3 seems to replace the filename's underscore with hyphens, so the layout should be specified as `test-layout`:

```js
// blog/index.vue
export default {
  // layout: 'test_layout', // ❌ replace underscore with hyphen

  layout: 'test-layout', // ✅
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt3-custom-layout?file=pages%2Fblog%2Findex.vue)

This [wasn't an issue in Nuxt 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-custom-layout?file=pages%2Fblog%2Findex.vue), which uses the exact filename as the layout name (including underscores). I also don't see any documentation about this. I've reported the [issue](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/2518) to get some clarification.

Comment: I think this syntax should be replaced with  new [NuxtLayout](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/components/nuxt-layout#nuxtlayout) component, I tried the layout option and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Remove below code from your layout file. This may work.

```html
<script>
    export default {
      name: "test_layout"
    }
</script>
```